# Can you use the value of an Array as a Comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var hits = ["a", "b", "c"];

if (hits !== ["a", "b", "c"]){
//Do some stuff here
};
```

Can you use the value of an array as a comparsion? The above does not seem to work for me I was wondering if this is the way to go about it or if there is another way to access the literal value of an array for comparison.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: You could easily write a function for array comparision.

Comment: You can't compare arrays like that, because arrays are objects. And when you use comparison operator over an object, its reference will be compared and the comparison result will be returned.

Answer (score 5):

The equality operators (`===` and `!==`) compare **references, not values** in case of objects. Mind that in JavaScript Arrays are objects. Because of that and because these are two distinct arrays (they look the same, they contain the same values, but they're not the same array) their references differ:

> If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

**Note:** `==` and `!=` equality operators also compare objects by references, but since they do more than just simple comparison (and it's often unexpected), it's generally advised not to use them and always stick to strict equality operators (`===` and `!==`).

## How to compare arrays then?

There are at least a few different methods. Some people advise to compare `JSON.stringify` of both arrays but, even though it works for simple cases, it's not really a good solution performance-wise. You can find better methods here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/704894

If you happen to use some kind of utility library such as `lodash` or `underscore` this function is already there! See https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

Comment: so what about `==` and `!=`? wont they compare references?

Comment: So why does `'a' === 'a'` return `true`?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yes, they will. I added this to my answer.

Comment: @Tresdin as I said, in case of **objects** equality operators compare them by references. Primitives such as strings are compared by value. Read more about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: @Michal Miszczyszyn Out of curiosity what is the reference value of              ["a", "b", "c"] in the if statement?

Comment: @LojikOverload probably some memory address, distinct from the one `hits` have, but for the details I'd have to look into the specification. It doesn't matter though, because you're not able to get this address from JavaScript anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this

```
if (JSON.stringify(hits) === JSON.stringify(["a", "b", "c"])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way because of the way Javascript handles arrays - it's not checking the values are the same, it's checking that the object is the same object (which it isn't).

Comment: This is actually not a good idea. What if you had something like this in an array? `['a,b', 'b', 'c']` and in a second one something like this: `['a', 'b,b', 'c']`? It would return `true`, but those are not same arrays.

Comment: Hmm, yes of course - I will remove the suggested code